# VBA error: Error 1004: Error Method range of object _worksheet failed

Tags: vba

I am trying to create VBA for this function - to delete rows if cell in column A contains "BG01". Header name for column A is "Payment Center"

But when I run the macro, it shows: Error Method range of object _worksheet failed

```
row_number = 1

Do
    DoEvents
    row_number = row_number + 1
    Payment_Center = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number) ' <~~~~~ Error occurs here

    If InStr(Payment_Center, "BG01") >= 1 Then
        Sheet1.Rows(row_number & ":" & row_number).Delete
        row_number = row_number - 1
    End If

Loop Until Payment_Center = " "
```

Answer (score 0):

The error happens because the range object needs to be modified using the `Set` keyword.

```
Set Payment_Center = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number)
```

and your loop should look like

```
row_number = 1

Do
  DoEvents
  row_number = row_number + 1
  Set Payment_Center = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number) '

  If InStr(Payment_Center, "BG01") >= 1 Then
    Sheet1.Rows(row_number & ":" & row_number).Delete
    row_number = row_number - 1

  End If

  ' reset Payment_Center range using new row number
  set Payment_Center = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number)

Loop Until Payment_Center = " "
```

and it should work

it would also help your coding and debugging if you had `Option Explicit` at the top of **all** your code modules, and declared all variables properly, such as

```
Dim row_number As Integer
Dim Payment_Center as Range
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. However, its now showing runtime error 424. Object required at this section Loop Until Payment_Center = " "

Comment: that's because after you change the range, or delete the row, the range `Payment_Center` is no longer set, so you have to set it again in the loop

Comment: @Siti: I have edited my answer to give more information, and changed your loop.

Comment: I have tried but now its showing runtime error 91 for this section 
    *Payment_Center = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number) ' *

Should I adjust anything in the variable?

Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: @Siti: sorry, I had made a mistake in my code, of course, as I had said, to modify a range object you must always use the `Set` keyword, thus the code should have been:

 `Set Payment_Center = Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number)`

I have changed it, please try again